# PostgreSql: how to update table from array?

Tags: postgresql

How to update table fields from array to avoid temp table using?
User passes array to reorder table.

```
create TABLE items
(
id serial primary key,
name text, 
select_order int
)

insert into items(name, select_order)
values
('cucumber',0),
('milk',1),
('coffee',2),
('water',3)

select * from items order by select_order;

DO
$body$
DECLARE var_array int[]:='{3,0,2,1}';
BEGIN
update items ??

END;
$body$
```

The final result in this example should be

```
select * from items order by select_order;
name        select_order
------------------------
water       0
cucumber    1
coffee      2
milk        3
```

Comment: Can be a little more specific? How do want this `update` to happen? I cannot figure it out from your question, `var_array` is just a list of `integer`s.

Comment: Index in the input array is a corresponding old position. As I see from answers below th "ordinality" is a right way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the index in the array corresponds to the value in `select_order` the following query returns the new and old value:

```
select i.id, i.select_order, t.new_sort
from items i
   join lateral unnest(array[3,0,2,1]) with ordinality as t(new_sort, idx) on t.idx - 1 = i.select_order
```

Now this can be used to update the target table:

```
update items
  set select_order = r.new_sort
from (
  select i.id, i.select_order, t.new_sort
  from items i
    join lateral unnest(array[3,0,2,1]) with ordinality as t(new_sort, idx) on t.idx - 1 = i.select_order
) r
where r.id = items.id;
```

This also assumes that `select_order` starts a `0` and has no gaps.